# Creating a Javascript object array on the fly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

Ideally I would like to create an object array in JavaScript like this:

```
var items = [
  ['test', 2],
  ['test1', 4],
  ['test2', 6]
];

    var test_1 = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        test_1.items[i][0] = items[i][1];
    }
```

So, once done I'd like to be able to call

`test_1.test` which would equal 2.

Is this doable?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the bracket notation as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

> ```
> object.property     // dot notation
> object["property"]  // bracket notation
> ```

```js
var items = [
  ['test', 2],
  ['test1', 4],
  ['test2', 6]
];

var test_1 = {};

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    test_1[items[i][0]] = items[i][1];
    //    ^           ^
}

console.log(test_1);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina! That's great